# Tkinter app doesn't keep proportions when moved in other screen or run through ssh

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, resize

I've built a GUI using `Tkinter`. On my dual monitor local machine, the appearance of the gui is as it was designed for.

[image]

I have the following issues though:

1. If I move the window to the second monitor, then the frames inside the main window don't resize according to the dimensions of the new monitor, so the gui looks like so [image] I guess it has to do with the fact that I'm using the size of the monitor that the app is open to `columnconfigure` my frames.

   `screen_width  = int(window.winfo_geometry().split('x', 1)[0])`

   `tab_Digitizer.columnconfigure(0, minsize=int(0.75*screen_width), weight=80)`
2. The second issue is that, if I connect from a remote machine (`MacOS` with `XQuartz`) using `ssh`, by default a small window opens and my gui looks like so
   [image]
   Oddly enough if I maximize the window, the layout gets completely messed up
   [image]

Since I just started in Python and Tkinter probably I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Is there a way to automatically resize/rescale/shrink everything depending on the dimensions of the root window?

Also is it possible to do the same for the children of every parent i.e. widgets inside a frame

The code I have is super big to paste here, so I'm giving a link to it
https://pastebin.com/hHEYJ1bR but I have a snippet that might help

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import screeninfo
from screeninfo import get_monitors

import os

# Method to make Label(Widget) invisible
def hide_frame(frame):
    # This will remove the widget
    frame.grid_remove()
    
# Method to make Label(widget) visible
def show_frame(frame, c, r, S, pdx):
    # This will recover the widget
    frame.grid(column=c, row=r, sticky=S, ipadx=(pdx,0))
    
# Method to make Label(widget) visible
def show_frame_padx(frame, c, r, S, pdx):
    # This will recover the widget
    frame.grid(column=c, row=r, sticky=S, padx=(pdx,0))
    
    
    
def populate(frame, rows):
    '''Put in some fake data'''
    for row in range(rows):
        tk.Label(frame,
                 text = "%s" % row,
                ).grid(row=row, column=0)
        
        t="Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah %s" %row
        
        tk.Label(frame, text=t).grid(row    = row,
                                     column = 1,
                                     sticky = EW    
                                    )
#____________________________________________________________________________________________   
#This will be the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(True, True)
window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
window.title("DICER daq")
default_font = tkinter.font.Font(font='TkDefaultFont')
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.update()

screen_width  = int(window.winfo_geometry().split('x', 1)[0])
screen_height = int(window.winfo_geometry().split('x', 1)[1].split('+', 1)[0])

#____________________________________________________________________________________________
#Upper frame


frame_logo = Frame(window, bd=10)
frame_logo.place(rely=0.0, relx=0.0, relwidth=1.0)

logo_label = tk.Label(frame_logo, text="daq", fg="red", font='Helvetica 18 bold')
logo_label.pack(anchor=W)

label_version = tk.Label(frame_logo, text="version test.0", fg="blue")
label_version.pack(side=LEFT)


#____________________________________________________________________________________________
#Lower frame
frame_main = Frame(window)
frame_main.place(rely=0.10, relx=0.0, relwidth=1.0)

#Create a tabcontrol
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(frame_main)
tabControl.grid(column=0, row=1)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Digitizer tab
tab_Digitizer    = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab_Digitizer, text='   Digitizer   ')
tab_Digitizer.columnconfigure(0, minsize=int(0.75*screen_width), weight=80)
tab_Digitizer.columnconfigure(1, minsize=75,                     weight=10)
tab_Digitizer.columnconfigure(2, minsize=75,                     weight=10)



#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#This is to select available digitizer channels

def Digitizer_channel_selection(event):
    print ("Digitizer channel selected:", var_digitizer_channel.get() )
    pass
    
lbl_general_board_settings = Label(tab_Digitizer, text="Digitizer channel number", font='-weight bold')
lbl_general_board_settings.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)

opt_digitizer_channel = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
var_digitizer_channel = IntVar(tab_Digitizer)
var_digitizer_channel.set(opt_digitizer_channel[0]) # default value
digitizer_channel     = OptionMenu(tab_Digitizer, var_digitizer_channel, *opt_digitizer_channel, command = Digitizer_channel_selection)
digitizer_channel.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=NSEW)




#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#General board settings


lbl_general_board_registers = Label(tab_Digitizer,
                                    text  = "General board registers",
                                    font  = '-weight bold',
                                   )
                                   
lbl_general_board_registers.grid(column = 0,
                                 row    = 1,
                                 sticky = W
                                )

btn_hide_general_board_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer,
                                          text    = "Hide",
                                          font    = '-weight bold',
                                          command = lambda: hide_frame(frame_general_board_registers)
                                         )
                                         
btn_hide_general_board_registers.grid(column = 1,
                                      row    = 1,
                                      sticky = EW
                                     )


btn_show_general_board_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer,
                                          text    = "Show",
                                          font    = '-weight bold',
                                          command = lambda: show_frame_padx(frame_general_board_registers, 0, 2, EW, 0)
                                         )
                                         
btn_show_general_board_registers.grid(column = 2,
                                      row    = 1,
                                      sticky = EW
                                     )

frame_general_board_registers = Frame(tab_Digitizer
                                     )

frame_general_board_registers.columnconfigure(0, minsize=int(0.49*0.75*screen_width), weight=50)
frame_general_board_registers.columnconfigure(1, minsize=int(0.25*0.75*screen_width), weight=25)
frame_general_board_registers.columnconfigure(2, minsize=int(0.25*0.75*screen_width), weight=25)
frame_general_board_registers.config(highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=3)
                                   
frame_general_board_registers.grid(column  = 0,
                                   row     = 2,
                                   sticky  = EW,
                                   ipadx   = 0
                                  )
                                  
populate(frame_general_board_registers, 35)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Channel settings

lbl_channel_registers = Label(tab_Digitizer,
                              text = "Channel registers",
                              font = '-weight bold'
                             )
                             
lbl_channel_registers.grid(column = 0,
                           row    = 3,
                           sticky = W
                          )

btn_hide_channel_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer,
                                    text="Hide",
                                    font="-weight bold",
                                    command=lambda: hide_frame(frame_channel_registers)
                                   )
btn_hide_channel_registers.grid(column = 1,
                               row     = 3,
                               sticky  = EW
                              )


btn_show_channel_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer,
                                    text    = "Show",
                                    font    = '-weight bold',
                                    command = lambda: show_frame_padx(frame_channel_registers, 0, 4, W, 0)
                                   )

btn_show_channel_registers.grid(column = 2,
                                row    = 3,
                                sticky = EW
                               )

frame_channel_registers = Frame(tab_Digitizer
                               )
                               
frame_channel_registers.grid(column = 0,
                             row    = 4,
                             sticky = W
                            )
                            
frame_channel_registers.columnconfigure(0, minsize=int(0.840*0.75*screen_width), weight=84)
frame_channel_registers.columnconfigure(1, minsize=int(0.075*0.75*screen_width), weight=8)
frame_channel_registers.columnconfigure(2, minsize=int(0.075*0.75*screen_width), weight=8)
frame_channel_registers.config(highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=3)

##Channel settings - PSD
def onFrameConfigure(event):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    
def handle_user_scrolling_up(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-5, "units")
    
def handle_user_scrolling_down(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(5, "units")
    
def handle_scrollbar_scrolling(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


lbl_PSD_channel_registers = Label(frame_channel_registers,
                                  text = "DPP-PSD registers",
                                  font = (default_font.actual(), "10", "bold")
                                 )
                                 
lbl_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column = 0,
                               row    = 3,
                               ipadx  = 20,
                               sticky = W)

btn_hide_PSD_channel_registers = Button(frame_channel_registers,
                                        text    = "Hide",
                                        font    = (default_font.actual(), "10", "bold"),
                                        command = lambda: [hide_frame(canvas), hide_frame(myscrollbar)]
                                       )
                                       
btn_hide_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column = 1,
                                    row    = 3,
                                    sticky = EW
                                   )


btn_show_PSD_channel_registers = Button(frame_channel_registers,
                                        text    = "Show",
                                        font    = (default_font.actual(), "10", "bold"),
                                        command = lambda: [show_frame_padx(canvas, 0, 4, EW, 50), show_frame_padx(myscrollbar, 1, 4, NS, 0)])

btn_show_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column = 2,
                                    row    = 3,
                                    sticky = EW
                                   )

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame_channel_registers,
                   height      = int(0.20*screen_height)
                  )
                  
frame_PSD_channel_registers = Frame(canvas
                                   )
                                   
frame_PSD_channel_registers.grid(column = 0,
                                 row    = 0,
                                 sticky = EW
                                )

frame_PSD_channel_registers.bind("<Button-4>" , handle_user_scrolling_up)
frame_PSD_channel_registers.bind("<Button-5>" , handle_user_scrolling_down)
frame_PSD_channel_registers.bind("<Configure>", handle_scrollbar_scrolling)

myscrollbar=Scrollbar(frame_channel_registers ,orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

myscrollbar.grid(column = 1,
                 row    = 4,
                 sticky = NS,
                 ipadx  = 0)

canvas.grid(column = 0,
            row    = 4,
            sticky = EW,
            padx  = (50,0))

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_PSD_channel_registers, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

canvas.columnconfigure(0, minsize=int(0.90*0.84*0.75*screen_width), weight=99)
canvas.columnconfigure(1, minsize=int(0.10*0.84*0.75*screen_width), weight=1)

frame_PSD_channel_registers.columnconfigure(0, minsize=int(0.20*0.84*0.75*screen_width), weight=20)
frame_PSD_channel_registers.columnconfigure(1, minsize=int(0.10*0.84*0.75*screen_width), weight=10)
frame_PSD_channel_registers.columnconfigure(2, minsize=int(0.60*0.84*0.75*screen_width), weight=50)
frame_PSD_channel_registers.config(highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)

populate(frame_PSD_channel_registers, 35)

#This keeps the window open - has to be at the end
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using pixels, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: @CoolCloud: Thanks for your comment! How can I change that but still using `grid`?

Comment: You have to manually find out what works with `grid()` and then use it. Plus, you cannot mix `pack()` and `grid()`.

Comment: @CoolCloud: be careful with that advice. You can mix `pack` and `grid` in an application as a whole, you just can't use them both for widgets that have a common parent. It's very common to use both to design a complex layout.

Comment: @BryanOakley True: So OP should make sure under `root`, you don't mix `pack()` and `grid()` but you can add a container and `grid` it in the root and have all the widgets inside the frame use `pack`